# Android: create list irrespective of object type

Tags: android

I have two classes like this:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    String id;
    String name;
    String email;
    String age;
    String full_name;

    public String getAboutCustomer() {
        return aboutCustomer;
    }

    public void setAboutCustomer(String aboutCustomer) {
        this.aboutCustomer = aboutCustomer;
    }

    String aboutCustomer;

    public void setFull_name(String full_name) {
        this.full_name = full_name;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }


    public String getFull_name() {
        return full_name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }


    public User() {
    }

    public User(String id, String name, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }



    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}



public class Message implements Serializable {
    String id, message, createdAt, type;
    User user;

    public Message() {
    }

    public Message(String id, String message, String createdAt, User user) {
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type){
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

and I would like to get a List from both of them. The problem is, I would like to create a method that is for both, so the type of the class is not relevant. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
public List<?> getList(){
        String s = sharedPrefsLists.getString(SharedPrefsInformation.GET_MAIN_FEED_LIST, null);
        return new Gson().fromJson(s,
                new TypeToken<List<?>>() {
                }.getType());
    }
```

But if I try something like this:
List lUser = getList(); It doesn't work. Android says that I have to cast, change the variable or make the method return the type "User".

How can I create a List irrespective of the type of the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a generic method by doing the following:

```
public <T> List<T> getList(){
    String s = sharedPrefsLists.getString(SharedPrefsInformation.GET_MAIN_FEED_LIST, null);
    return new Gson().fromJson(s,
            new TypeToken<List<T>>() {
            }.getType());
}
```

And then call the method assigning the result to a generic list as follows:

```
List<User> users = getList();
```

However, I do not know how you expect this method to be useful without passing in the shared preference to look up or somehow allow a different JSON string to be parsed.

Comment: Thank you so much! You made my day :)